# SQL Server: connect to local instance by using 

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have seen in some cases that a dot character (.) can be used when connecting into a local sql server instance. What is definition of . in this case? Is this documented in BOL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "The word localhost or a period (.) can be used in place of (local)"

in section "Connecting to the Local Server" of [ 1 ]

[ 1 ]
Creating a Valid Connection String Using TCP/IP
SQL Server 2008 R2
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191260.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start:

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/126660/local-server-not-found-with-dot-in-dts-import

https://serverfault.com/questions/11745/i-cannot-connect-to-my-local-sql-server-2008